# How to show Error Message When someone leave Empty Fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd, ant-design-pro

I want to add Error Message in my form. Currently i am working on ReactJs and i am absolute new new to reactJs i  used ant-design form and form is already validated but did not show error message in text when someone leave empty fields . Please help me out because i am really stuck . Thank You

**Form Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import Input from 'antd/lib/input';

const FormCard = styled.div`
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.41, 0.094, 0.54, 0.07) 0s;
  margin-top: 30px;
`;

const FormItem = styled.div`
  font-family: 'Chinese Quote', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI',
    'PingFang SC', 'Hiragino Sans GB', 'Microsoft YaHei', 'Helvetica Neue',
    Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji',
    'Segoe UI Symbol';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-variant: tabular-nums;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  vertical-align: top;
`;

class RegisterStepOne extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <FormCard>
          <FormItem label="E-mail">
            {getFieldDecorator('firstName', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your First name!',
                  whitespace: true,
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="First name" />)}
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem label="E-mail">
            {getFieldDecorator('lastName', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your Last name!',
                  whitespace: true,
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="Last name" />)}
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem label="E-mail">
            {getFieldDecorator('email', {
              rules: [
                {
                  type: 'email',
                  message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
                },
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="Email" />)}
          </FormItem>

          <FormItem>
            {getFieldDecorator('lastPosition', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your Last Position!',
                  whitespace: true,
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="Present or last position" />)}
          </FormItem>

          <FormItem>
            {getFieldDecorator('lastCompany', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your Last Company!',
                  whitespace: true,
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="Present or last Company" />)}
          </FormItem>
        </FormCard>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default RegisterStepOne;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used your code and applied the antd original demo.
you might have missed a thing or two, check it out : 
https://codepen.io/fawzisf/pen/RqyQVy

```js
const { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } = antd;

const FormItem = Form.Item;

class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
      <FormItem label="E-mail">
            {getFieldDecorator('firstName', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your First name!',
                  whitespace: true,
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="First name" />)}
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem label="E-mail">
            {getFieldDecorator('lastName', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your Last name!',
                  whitespace: true,
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="Last name" />)}
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem label="E-mail">
            {getFieldDecorator('email', {
              rules: [
                {
                  type: 'email',
                  message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
                },
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="Email" />)}
          </FormItem>

          <FormItem>
            {getFieldDecorator('lastPosition', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your Last Position!',
                  whitespace: true,
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="Present or last position" />)}
          </FormItem>

          <FormItem>
            {getFieldDecorator('lastCompany', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input your Last Company!',
                  whitespace: true,
                },
              ],
            })(<Input placeholder="Present or last Company" />)}
          </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
            valuePropName: 'checked',
            initialValue: true,
          })(
            <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
          )}
          <a className="login-form-forgot" href="">Forgot password</a>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
            Log in
          </Button>
          Or <a href="">register now!</a>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create()(NormalLoginForm);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedNormalLoginForm />, mountNode);
```

Comment: Thank You for your help